# How to install ubuntu live-server 21.10 on a iSCSI drive?

Tags: system-installation, 21.10, iscsi

I have to install Ubuntu 21.10 on iSCSI drive which is configured from BIOS menu, I remembered in Ubuntu 18.04 installation GUI, it had a step for user to configure iSCSI drive during installation by typing iSCSI target name and target IP, but I cannot find the step to configure iSCSI drive in Ubuntu 21.10, does anyone know how to install ubuntu 21.10 live-server image on iSCSI drive? Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Are you sure you want to do this? Ubuntu 21.10 will be supported for 9 months until July 2022 Only about 3 months and it is EOL

Comment: Actually I just would like to know how do I install ubuntu to an iSCSI drive after ubuntu 18.04 the GUI installation interface was changed, I can also install 22.04 when it's released but just would like to know how? thank you.